# Help me make a dense moving floor fog loop

Tags: animation, particles, smoke-simulation, loop

I am fairly new to blender and am animating a looped scene of a dark grimy room. I’ve tried making a still room fog just by changing some textures to a cube but I thought I could do better. I don’t really know much about smoke simulation but I would like to make a loop of slow moving dense fog/mist that sort of sticks to the floor. I also wanted the smoke to be emitted and around the room before the start of the animation if that makes sense.

I will also have various lights on it, If that matters to know.

I saw a post on stack exchange and someone used this image and I think its just about what I am looking to create. There will be no object moving on the floor so I am not really worried about it colliding with stuff.

[image: Fogexample]